# vba excel - pivot

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, pivot-table

each time while i run my vba code it sort B column then place row formula(for place sl.no) in B2 after it moves to next column ,then next...

issue is my column range may vary upto 1 - 40

i want my code to define last column & function the same from last column to B column

[image]

```
Range("B2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=row()-1"
Range("B2").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("B2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Columns("B:B").Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RP").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RP").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
    "C1:C5021"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RP").AutoFilter.Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
Range("C2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=row()-1"
Range("C2").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("C2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Columns("C:C").Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RP").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RP").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
    "D1:D5201"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RP").AutoFilter.Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

Comment: You forgot to actually ask a question.

Comment: i want the code which it directly goes to last column and do the function and then move to before column and repeat the same until B column

Comment: On here , my column ranges 1-10 but for every time i run it ,it way vary from 1-40

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.